# Bootstrap 4 two columns not aligning in a row

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

I've created a login form with bootstrap 4. I've two `col-md-6` columns in a row for 1. remember me 2. forgot password. but in mobile the forgot password jumps down from the row. I'm not getting why? any idea? thanks.

here is screenshot:

[image]

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="" class="custom-control-input"><span class="custom-control-label">Remember me</span>
        </label>                  
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
        <a href="#" class="text-primary">forgot password?</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: the md in col-md-6  is for your device size.   try using col-xs-6 or col-sm-6

see breakout points in docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

Comment: @developer I've tried `sm` it didn't work

Comment: As developer said, xs, sm, md and lg all are checking your device size (desktop eg. is lg and tablet is md), so they all must be used separately. Here's a tutorial link: https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system

Comment: @MiskaRantala I'm using bootstrap 4

Comment: also as these are clearly wrapping - there is nothing which stops you using other techniques for positioning these.  i.e. just create floated divs with disiplay:inline-block on them - not using bootstrap for these parts??

Comment: Here's a link to the 4: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp . It tells to use `col-`

Comment: without bootstrap for this section: https://jsfiddle.net/4fc8z7dq/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove **md** if you want styles to apply for smaller devices.
You declare that the style should apply only if the device is bigger than 768px by specifying **md**.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 text-left">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="" class="custom-control-input"><span class="custom-control-label">Remember me</span>
        </label>                  
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <a href="#" class="text-primary">forgot password?</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

You can read more about bootstrap grids: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using v4 of bootstrap (which your tags say that you use) then you can just do the following:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col">
   content 
 </div>
 <div class="col">
   content 
 </div>
</div>
```

[Documentation for v4 grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 0):

you used col-md-6 for tablet device (768px - 992px)

but as a default your div be col-12 **in mobile** (0 - 576px)

that`s why you can add your custom grid for mobile

eg: first div: `class="col-4"` second div: `class="col-8"`

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 col-md-6 text-left">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="" class="custom-control-input"><span class="custom-control-label">Remember me</span>
        </label>                  
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-6 text-right">
        <a href="#" class="text-primary">forgot password?</a>
      </div>
</div>
```